# Folium Choropleth "key_on" issue

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

I have a issue concerning the Choropleth function in folium.

```
state_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

mssp = folium.Map()

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data='geodata.geojson',
    name='choropleth',
    data=state_data,
    columns=['District', 'Rooms'],
    key_on='feature.id',
    fill_color='YlGn',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Rooms'
).add_to(mssp)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(mssp)

mssp
```

My CSV:

```
    Price,Condo,Size,Rooms,Toilets,Suites,Parking,Elevator,Furnished,SwimmingPool,New,District,NegotiationType,PropertyType,Latitude,Longitude
930,220,47,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,Artur Alvim,rent,apartment,-23.543138,-46.479486
```

My GeoJSON:

```
    {
  "type": "GeometryCollection",
  "geometries": [{
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "id": "Artur Alvim",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            [-46.501092999999997, -23.545874999999999],
            [-46.501199999999997, -23.545991999999998],
            [-46.501261, -23.546139],
            [-46.502249999999997, -23.54945]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried several different 'key_on' values, but nothing is working. It just draws the Districts (for easier reading I left out some coordinates in the GeoJSON, but that doesn't matter) and the legend.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help and especially explain this to me.

[How the output currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS5LU.jpg) (with Price as selected column, but Rooms doesn't work either)

Thanks in addition!

Answer (score 2):

Modify `key_on` parameter from:

```
key_on=feature.id
```

to

```
key_on=feature.geometries.id
```

`id` is under `geometries` so you should put it there as well.